# Environment Variables Visual Studio Code for Mac with Python Jupyter

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, jupyter

Where do you set the environment variables for Jupyter in Visual Studio Code for Mac?

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of things you can do (I work on the jupyter extension)

1. Set environment variables before starting VS code from the command line.
2. Create a 'runStartupCommands' entry for jupyter. Something like so in your settings.json:

```
"jupyter.runStartupCommands": ["import os;os.environ['TEST'] = '1'"]
```

3. Run that same code in a cell at the start of the notebook.