# How can I create environment variables for Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

In my VS Code `settings.json` file, I can use the following option to define environment variables:

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.osx" : {
    "MY_ENV": "test"
    "MY_ENVTYPE": "qa"
}
```

Now whenever, I start a new shell in the workspace, the shell loads with the above environment variables, and I can access them typically with `os.environ["MY_ENV"]` is my python scripts.

But with the same `settings.json`, if I try to access the environment variables in a Nupyter Notebook I get `None`. So my question is, is there a way to define environment variables in VS Code's `settings.json` file, so whenever I start a new notebook, the environment variables are loaded by default.

Currently the workaround I have found is to add the following code snippet in a top code cell.

```py
import os
os.environ["MY_ENV"] = "test"
os.environ["MY_ENVTYPE"] = "qa"
```

I am hoping there is a better way to do the same thing.

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68563776/12444149), if you use a virtual environment you can export variable in `activate` script so every new kernel for notebook will have it set as well

Comment: I don't see the command `jupyter.runStartupCommands` in the intellisense, i think that's removed.

Comment: Then you can try my suggestion of using virtual environment, i just tested it and it works.

Comment: okay, just found out that setting is available only in user setting, not in workspace setting of vscode. I am unclear of how to export variable in activate script, I am using conda for virtual env, can you post that as an answer? that would be really helpful.

Comment: Never used conda but according to [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#set-env-vars) you just have to create `env_vars` file

Comment: cool, thanks for sharing the doc, I will look into it. Thanks again for your time

Comment: I am also looking for an answer without using the `activate` script - because when you change a variable, you have to reload the entire VS Code window with `Developer: Reload Window`. None of the proposed answers make it easy to update env vars using the jupyter env.

Comment: I think just restarting the kernel should work fine @j7skov

Comment: @monte - It does not work. I wish it would! I've got a similar question out there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73858371/is-there-a-way-to-apply-new-environment-variables-in-a-virtual-environment-in-vs/73861509#73861509

Answer (score 5):

We could use [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) to solve this problem.
Using "pip install python-dotenv" to install the package.
To configure the development environment Please add .env file in the root directory of the project:

```
.
├── . env
└── test. py
```

Then we can use the following code to load environment:

```
%load_ext dotenv
%dotenv
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following command in `settings.json` to setup environment variables which are specific to just jupyter notebook. Feels a bit hackish though.

Using `jupyter.runStartupCommands`, I am executing bunch of python commands to define environment variables and load jupyter extension. Note each command is separated by a newline character.

```
"jupyter.runStartupCommands": [
        "import os\nos.environ['MY_ENV']='mltest'\nos.environ['MY_ENVTYPE']='qa'\n%load_ext autoreload\n%autoreload 2"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jupyter extension supports .env files. You can use that ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10718#issuecomment-1179206006)).

You can also define environment variables in the kernel's kernel.json file- in the `env` property (see also [this answer post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53595397/11107541)).

I assume the `%env` and `%set_env` magics would work as well (see also [this answer post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44251637/11107541)).

Comment: The `%env` and `%set_env` magic commands do not always work, and they can make a working setup fail. See [How to Solve "CUDA: Invalid Device Ordinal" Error in PyTorch Single-GPU Inference on a Model Trained with DataParallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77856985/11154841).