# How to make Jupyter Notebook run on one specified gpu of multi-gpus

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, gpu

I have some PyTorch code in one Jupyter Notebook which needs to run on one specified GPU (that is, not 'GPU 0') since others already work on 'GPU 0'. I have tried this:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'
```

But this does not work. How do I run the code on one specified GPU successfully?

Comment: I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71964589/15214228) to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may launch Jupyter Notebook with, say, `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1`. This usually what I do on cluster, because PyTorch doc recommends setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` compared to `torch` functions like [`torch.cuda.set_device(device)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.set_device.html):

```bash
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 jupyter notebook &
```

You can also check what device is available in your notebook using [`torch.cuda.is_available()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.is_available.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable for `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` at the beginning of the same Jupyter Notebook cell that has the code that puts the model on the device.

Set the environment variable with:

```py
!export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5,6,7
```

**And not in Python, neither**

```py
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="4,5,6,7"
```

**nor:**

```py
%set_env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5,6,7
```

There are ways to make this setting a default: .bashrc, kernel.json, Jupyter Service settings (all untested), see Stack Overflow [How to set env variable in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77857149/11154841).

##### Proof

Here is a code proof that setting the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` env var in Python makes already working code that runs `!export ...` in the beginning fail again, see [How to Solve "CUDA: Invalid Device Ordinal" Error in PyTorch Single-GPU Inference on a Model Trained with DataParallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77856985/11154841).